# In Next JS 13.4 We have a Want to create a table with filter options at the top

Tags: components, next.js13

Create a table with filter options at the top. Filters is a client component and Table is a Server component at the same level under a parent server component. Need a solution where we can transfer the Filters values to a server component so that the server component can fetch the data according to filtered values.

Share the sample code to achieve the same.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).